# ¿Cómo usar AVG, SUM o MAX para comparación luego de un where o having?

Tags: mysql, sql

Me gustaría que me informaran como utilizar estos tres operadores (AVG, MAX y SUM) en MySQL luego de un Where o Having.

Sé que normalmente se utiliza luego de un Select pero necesito compararlo y no sé el como.

Cómo ejemplo; Tengo una base de datos y necesito sacar aquellos empleados con un salario mayor a la media.

```
Select * FROM plantilla where Salario>avg(plantilla.salario)
```

Lo intenté remplazando el where por Having pero sin resultado.

Muchísimas gracias.

Comment: edita tu pregunta y muestra bajo que escenario específico las quieres usar, es decir que es lo que tratas de obtener?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Lo mejor para lo que quiere lograr es usar una **subconsulta** en tu consulta principal, tal como muestra a continuación:

```
SELECT * FROM plantilla 
WHERE salario > (SELECT AVG(SALARIO) 
                 FROM PLANTILLA)
```

La subconsulta en este caso, está después de la clausura `WHERE` y esta solo otorgará de vuelta el ***promedio del salario de la tabla plantilla***, que luego será utilizado por el `WHERE` para comparar el salario

[Te dejo documentación en español sobre las subconsultas](http://mysql.localhost.net.ar/doc/refman/5.0/es/subqueries.html)

Comment: Excelente, era lo que necesitaba. Gracias.